# Problem in setting the position of text

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (image) 
{\includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{imag/pic1.png}
};
\node
[
    fill=teal,
    align=r north west,
    text=white,
    font={}
] at (pic1.r north west) {Sum is here};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
```

I am moving text (Sum is here) to left side of the image . I have tried
r west,l north. But text is not moving. How i can do it?

Comment: Please edit your posting to make your code minimally compilable. Don't rely on others to be able to guess which document class you employ and which packages must be loaded in order to make your code compilable.

Comment: There is no such `align` in standard tikz, so you have errors or are using some preamble you don't show. Or, probably, both. Please complete your example to be compilable (I think this has been commented to you several times already). Although my cristal ball suggests to try with `anchor=north west` and `pic1.north west`...

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/702343/plus-sign-is-missing-in-equation#comment1746913_702343

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I really think that you should read some of the relevant parts of the [Ti*k*Z manual](https://tikz.dev) especially those covering nodes, their naming and anchors. A lot is wrong here: If you want to position a node relative to another, you need to use the name of the other node which is the part in parentheses. The  name of the node containing the image in your example is `image`. So, you could use this name in combination with an anchor to positition the second node, such as `at (image.west)`. You also need to set the anchor for the current node using the option `anchor=east`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it:

- kindly watch that all node-position refer to its center
- first: double anchors
- 2nd + 3rd: specifying anchor in polar coordinates

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (A) at (0,0) {\includegraphics{example-image-a}};
    \node[anchor=east,draw=blue!30] at (A.north west) {Sum is here};
    \node[anchor=east,draw=blue!30] at (A.160) {Sum is here};
    \node[anchor=east,draw=blue!30] at (A.180) {Sum is here};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```